# Browsersync not refreshing on updates when using API?

Tags: html, node.js, browser-sync

### Short Question Version

Changes to files happen below a `target` directory.  I have browsersync setup like this:

```
    var bs = require("browser-sync").create();

    // Start the browsersync server
    bs.init({
        server: './target'
    });

    bs.reload("*.html");
```

However this is not detecting changes that occur in `target` subdirectories and refreshing the browser.  Seems that the above lines are not enough?

### Long Question Version

I have built a CLI.  It watches for CSS changes in `src/main/css` and compiles the CSS (Using PostCSS) to `target/main/css`.  The same is enabled for html templates in `src/main/html`.

[Gaze](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gaze) watches for file changes and runs the functions that performs the compiling and this part works fine.

The full [source code can be seen here](https://github.com/superflycss/cli/blob/master/index.js#L207).

I was hoping BrowserSync would pickup on the file changes in the `target` directory and refresh the browser when edits are performed, however I'm not seeing any refreshes.  I have BrowserSync setup like this within the `serve` command:

```
    var bs = require("browser-sync").create();

    // Start the browsersync server
    bs.init({
        server: './target'
    });

    bs.reload("*.html");
```

The CLI can be tested by doing:

```
git clone https://github.com/superflycss/cli
cd cli
npm i -g
```

Or just install from NPM:

```
npm i -g @superflycss/cli
```

Then run:

```
sfc new project
cd project 
sfc serve
```

The `target` folder will open up in the browser.  Change the URL to `http://localhost:3000/test/html/`.  Edit the html in `src/test/html/index.html`.  The changes compile to `target/test/html/index.html` and BrowserSync should pickup on the changes IIUC...but it's not...

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty obvious, but `bs.reload("*.html");` has to be called from within the `on` event of the watcher.  So in other words whenever there is a file change call `bs.reload("*.html");`.

Since I'm using gaze to watch for file changes, I ended up doing this:

```
    gaze(PLI.SRC_MAIN_CSS, (err, watcher) => {

        if (err) {
            log('error', 'Error buliding src/main/css/ content.');
            throw new Error(err);
        }

        /**
         * Triggered both when new files are added and when files are changed.
         */
        watcher.on('changed', function (filepath) {
            buildMainCSS();
            bs.reload("*.html");                
        });
    });
```